# Symbol "¿" in XeTeX and LuaTeX shows in PDF as "£"

Tags: xetex, luatex, unicode, apa7

In this example code:

```
\documentclass{apa7}

\title{¿¿¿¿}
\shorttitle{¿¿}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{Independent}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

All `¿` symbols are changed to `£`. I tried this in MiKTeX and Overleaf, but this only happens with XeTeX and LuaTeX. What could be causing the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Or, specify the document class option `nofontenc`.

Comment: Use `\documentclass[nofontenc]{apa7}` to disable T1 font encoding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To have a shot at using the `apa7` document class under XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you need to load it with the class option `nofontenc`.

```
\documentclass[nofontenc]{apa7}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\title{¿¿¿¿}
\shorttitle{¿¿}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{Independent}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```